# Как сделать фигуру треугольника

Tags: css

Есть div с классом step - это просто линия с каким то фоном.
Потом есть div с классами: step_one, step_two, step_three на каждой странице эти шаги меняют фон.

Хочется сделать по другому.
Вот пример: идет синий фон Шаг 1, фон стал зеленый с треугольником вправо;
Шаг 2, оба блока зеленые и стрелка(треугольник) теперь на втором блоке и так т.д.
Вопрос как сделать треугольник? И вставить его ровно? Чтобы фон не перекрывал его.

```
.step{
width: 100%;
height:50px;
background: #0294B5;    
box-shadow: 8px 8px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-o-box-shadow:8px 8px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:8px 8px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow:8px 8px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

}

```
.step_one{
    float:left;
    width: 33.2%;
    height: 50px;

}
```

Далее шаги идут по аналогии.

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем понятно что вы хотите сделать. Думаю что то в этом роде.

http://codepen.io/Zoxon/pen/QjEdyR

```css
.b-container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}
.b-step-bar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.b-step-bar__item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
  line-height: 18px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.b-step-bar__item a,
.b-step-bar__item a:visited,
.b-step-bar__item a:hover {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px 9px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.b-step-bar__item:before,
.b-step-bar__item:after {
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-width: 18px 0 18px 18px;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.b-step-bar__item:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  left: 0;
}
.b-step-bar__item:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #dfdfdf;
  z-index: 1;
}
.b-step-bar__item:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}
.b-step-bar__item:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
.b-step-bar__item:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
.b-step-bar__item:hover {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
.b-step-bar__item:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #d4d4d4;
}
.b-step-bar__item_active {
  background-color: #a6ce39;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.b-step-bar__item_active a,
.b-step-bar__item_active a:visited,
.b-step-bar__item_active a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.b-step-bar__item_active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #a6ce39;
}
.b-step-bar__item_active:hover {
  background-color: #a6ce39;
}
.b-step-bar__item_active:hover:after {
  border-left-color: #a6ce39;
}
.b-step-bar_size_xl .b-step-bar__item a,
.b-step-bar_size_xl .b-step-bar__item a:visited,
.b-step-bar_size_xl .b-step-bar__item a:hover {
  padding: 10px 31px 9px 53px;
}
.b-step-bar_size_xl .b-step-bar__item:before,
.b-step-bar_size_xl .b-step-bar__item:after {
  border-width: 27px 0 27px 27px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="b-container">
  <div class="b-step-bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item b-step-bar__item_active"><a href="#">Шаг 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="b-step-bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item b-step-bar__item_active"><a href="#">Шаг 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="b-step-bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item b-step-bar__item_active"><a href="#">Шаг 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="b-step-bar">
    <ul>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item b-step-bar__item_active"><a href="#">Шаг 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="b-step-bar b-step-bar_size_xl">
    <ul>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item b-step-bar__item_active"><a href="#">Название<br/>в две строки</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="b-step-bar b-step-bar_size_xl">
    <ul>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Название<br/>в две строки</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item b-step-bar__item_active"><a href="#">Шаг 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="b-step-bar b-step-bar_size_xl">
    <ul>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Название<br/>в две строки</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item b-step-bar__item_active"><a href="#">Шаг 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="b-step-bar b-step-bar_size_xl">
    <ul>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Название<br/>в две строки</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item"><a href="#">Шаг 3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="b-step-bar__item b-step-bar__item_active"><a href="#">Шаг 4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Треугольник сплошного цвета проще всего сделать бордерами. Либо картинками.

Comment: Меня не покидает ощущение, что это всё можно сократить в разы...

Comment: А ещё правый треугольник некликабелен.

Answer (score -1):

Про треугольники и другие фигуры на CSS можно почитать [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/126207/).

Comment: Я читал вставляется он криво, как исправить?

Comment: Тогда поясните, что вы именно у вас криво и как должно быть.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).